# Accessing variables of an object of a particular class through a different class within the constructor of latter class

Tags: java, object

In the code below, I've added two lines that print output. The first line prints junk as usual, but surprisingly the second one gives me a compilation error. Why?

```
class Student {

  private String name;

  public Student(String name){
         this.name = name;
  }
  public String getName(){
         return name;
  }
}

class StudentServer {

   public StudentServer(){

          Student[] s = new Student[30];
          s[0] = new Student("Nick");

          // LINE 01: This compiles, although prints junk
          System.out.println(s[0]); 

          // LINE 02: I get a error called cannot find symbol
          System.out.println(s[0].getName());
   }

  public static void main(){
         new StudentServer();
  }
}
```

Comment: What symbol does it claim that it cannot find?

Comment: Works on my machine (once I added `String[] args` as a parameter to main).

Comment: How can the first line print anything if the second line doesn't compile?

Comment: Compiles quite fine and prints "Nick".

Comment: Im sorry, I shortened a large problem into a small one. I guess my conversion was bad. I will repost the question

Comment: @Haxed: just edit *this* question (or deleted it before reposting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with `main` method not being a proper application entry point aside, this code should compile and run just fine. The problem seems to lie elsewhere, and there's not enough information at the moment to identify the source.

#### Related questions

- [Java Beginner question about String[] args in the main method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885160/java-beginner-question-about-string-args-in-the-main-method)
- [Exception in thread “main” java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496073/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-main)

---

#### On `toString()`

The reason why printing `s[0]` "prints junk as usual" is because you didn't `@Override` the `toString()` method inherited from `Object`.

If you had just added this method:

```
@Override public String toString() {
   return "Student : " + name;
}
```

then printing `s[0]` wouldn't print "junk"; it would print whatever the above `toString()` returns (which in this case, is something reasonably "not junk").

#### Related questions

- [toString() in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161228/tostring-in-java)
- [Is toString() only useful for debugging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563676/is-tostring-only-useful-for-debugging)
- [when to use toString() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329168/when-to-use-tostring-method)

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```