# Java return arrays

Tags: java, arrays, return, tostring

I'm having trouble returning arrays from a custom method. It compiles fine but I get back:

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@20cf2c80
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I use:

```
System.out.println(getItem(1));
```

code:

```
public static String[] getItem(int e) {

String[] stats = new String[7];

            String name = "Null";
            String desc = "None";
            String typeOf = "0";
            String attackAdd = "0";
            String defenseAdd = "0";
            String canSell = "true";
            String canEat = "false";
            String earnedCoins = "0";



            if (e == 1) {

        name = "Pickaxe";
        desc = "Can be used to mine with.";
        typeOf = "2";
        }

      return new String[] { name, desc, typeOf};

    }
```

Help? :\

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `toString()` method of an array object actually doesn't go through and produce a string representation of the contents of the array, which is what I think you wanted to do. For that you'll need [`Arrays.toString()`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(java.lang.Object[])).

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getItem(1)));
```

The notation `[Ljava.lang.String` is Java code for a `String` array - in general, the default string representation of an array is `[L` followed by the type of the array's elements. Then you get a semicolon and the memory address (or some sort of locally unique ID) of the array.

Answer (score 2):

That's not an error. The JVM simply prints the address of the array since it doesn't print its content. Try this and see what happens now?

```
System.out.println(getItem(1)[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

#### On `Object.toString()`

The reason why you're getting such string is because arrays simply inherit and not `@Override` the [`Object.toString()`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) method.

> The `toString` method for `class Object` returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@`, and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:
>
> ```
>  getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
> ```

To return a `String` representation of an array that lists its elements, you can use e.g. [`Arrays.toString`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29), and for "multidimensional" arrays [`Arrays.deepToString`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29)

#### Related questions

- [toString() in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161228/tostring-in-java)
- [Simplest way to print an array in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/simplest-way-to-print-an-array-in-java)

On `deepEquals` and `deepToString` for "multidimensional" arrays:

- [Java Arrays.equals() returns false for two dimensional arrays.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721033/java-arrays-equals-returns-false-for-two-dimensional-arrays/)

---

#### On defining your own type

It needs to be said that your usage of `String[]` is not the best design choice.

Things would be so much better had you defined your own `class BasicItem` supported by various `enum`, with as many `final` fields as is practical to enforce immutability; perhaps something like this:

```
public enum ItemType {
   KNIFE, SWORD, AXE;
}
public enum Attribute {
   SELLABLE, EDIBLE;
}

public class BasicItem {

   final String name;
   final String desc;
   final ItemType type;

   final int attackAdd;
   final int defenseAdd;

   final Set<Attribute> attributes;
   //...
}
```

You should really take advantage all the benefits of good object-oriented design.

#### See also

- *Effective Java 2nd Edition*

  - Item 50: Avoid strings where other types are more appropriate
  - Item 25: Prefer lists to arrays
  - Item 30: Use enums instead of `int` constants
  - Item 32: Use [`EnumSet`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) instead of bit fields
  - Item 15: Minimize mutability
- [Java Tutorials/Enums](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)
- [Java Tutorials/Object Oriented Programming Concepts](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html)